# D3 + SVG, rotate around point, using mm units

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm creating an application where I need to use physical units (in my case mm) when drawing a rather complex 2d view using D3 + SVG. I can create all my objects and pan around without any issues, but I have stumbled upon the problem of rotation.

My code for creating the rectangles is basically

`var svgobject = svg.append("rect")
                         .attr("x", "10mm")
                         .attr("y", "10mm")
                         .attr("width", "5mm")
                         .attr("height", "5mm")
/*                       .attr("transform", "rotate(45 '20mm' '20mm')")*/;`

I need to rotate many of the objects around a point (often the centre of the object, but not always). I have however not been able to find a reliable way of specifying the reference point for the rotation.

The simplest way would be if I could just specify the rotation as shown above, but when I try to use mm for units in the rotation transform I get error messages similar to

> "Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="rotate(45 '20mm' '20mm')""

I have tried both with D3 and vanilla SVG, but I can't find any way.

My other plan of attack was to specify the rotational point in "svg units" instead, but I have not found a reliable way of converting from mm to svg units. When I try to get the x or y attribute of the object, I just get the mm attribute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been stuck on this particular problem for a few days now.

Comment: you can't rotate like that. You need to translate then rotate or rotate then translate

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my problem remains with this approach: I can't specify the translation or rotation in mm units, and I can't figure out a way to convert between "svg units" and mm.

Comment: you won't be able to to it in mm. You'll need an axis to take care of that I think

Comment: I've read a bit on svg axes, and I can not figure out how they could help me.. They seem to be for display purposes, or am I missing something?

Comment: maybe add some more code and we can see what you need. Set up a jsfiddle would be great.